# Using EntityManager unwrap method in a bean managed transaction

Tags: hibernate, jpa, jakarta-ee

I am using the Hibernate Session obtained from `em.unwrap(..)` method. I couldn't seem to find any info on whether I have to release it after usage. The transaction is managed by the bean and the entity manager is injected using `@Inject`.

```
    boolean transactionSuccess = false;
    try {
        utx.begin();
        final Session session = em.unwrap(Session.class);
        transactionSuccess = true;
    } finally {
        commitOrRollback(transactionSuccess);
    }
```

I presume that the entity manager instance is managed by the container. Since the Session is more or less the underlying implementation do I have to release it? It is `AutoCloseable` after all.

the only relevant info i found was this (but it seems vanilla JPA):
[After using the unwrap method on entitymanager to get the native hibernate session do I have to close both?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14402330/after-using-the-unwrap-method-on-entitymanager-to-get-the-native-hibernate-sessi)

Comment: You point to your own question for reference ...?

Comment: Sorry, mistake on my part. Fixed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, you requested an underlying object, the responsibility to close that object lies with the EntityManager.

Session to be AutoCloseable is reasonable when you work with unwrapped Hibernate.